# Authentication for Slim framework not working

Tags: php, slim

I am using Slim framework to create restful api.

I am able to create a get api, but when I add authentication to the get request, it throws an error(Advanced Rest client google chrome extension), here is the error :

```html
<html><head><title>Slim Application Error</title><style>body{margin:0;padding:30px;font:12px/1.5 Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;}h1{margin:0;font-size:48px;font-weight:normal;line-height:48px;}strong{display:inline-block;width:65px;}</style></head><body><h1>Slim Application Error</h1><p>The application could not run because of the following error:</p><h2>Details</h2><div><strong>Type:</strong> ErrorException</div><div><strong>Code:</strong> 8</div><div><strong>Message:</strong> Undefined variable: apiKey</div><div><strong>File:</strong> /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/v1/index.php</div><div><strong>Line:</strong> 34</div><h2>Trace</h2><pre>#0 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/v1/index.php(34): Slim\Slim::handleErrors(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/Library/WebSer...', 34, Array)
#1 [internal function]: authenticate(Object(Slim\Route))
#2 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Route.php(433): call_user_func_array('authenticate', Array)
#3 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Slim.php(1307): Slim\Route->dispatch()
#4 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(85): Slim\Slim->call()
#5 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(92): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#6 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#7 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/libs/Slim/Slim.php(1254): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#8 /Library/WebServer/Documents/pascal_api/rest_api/v1/index.php(100): Slim\Slim->run()
#9 {main}</pre></body></html>
```

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

function isValidApiKey($api_key) {
    $m = new MongoClient();
    $db = $m->pascal;
    $collection = $db->apiUsers;
    if($collection->findOne(array('apiKey' => $api_key))){
        return true;
    }

    else{ 
        return false;
    }

}

function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    // Getting request headers
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $response = array();
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    // Verifying Authorization Header
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {

        // get the api key
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        echo $apiKey;
        // validating api key
        //$db = new dbSupport();
        if ($isValidApiKey($api_key) === false) {

            // api key is not present
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
            echoRespnse(401, $response);
            $app->halt(401);

        }
        else{

        }
    } else {
        // api key is missing in header
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->halt(401);
    }
}


$app->get('/offerData','authenticate',function() use ($app) {

            $m = new MongoClient();
            $db = $m->pascal;
            $collection = $db->offerDetails;

            $offer_array = array();
            $cursor = $collection->find();
            $offer_array["offers"] = array();

            foreach ($cursor as $document) {

                $offerData = array('title' => $document['title'],
                             'discription' => $document['discription'],
                             'create_time' => $document['create_time'],
                             'expire_time' => $document['expire_time'],
                             'coordinates' => $document['loc']['coordinates'],
                             'address' => $document['address'],
                             'tags' => $document['tags'],
                             'phone_number' => $document['phone_number'],
                             'email' => $document['email'],
                             'website' => $document['website'],
                             'img_url' => $document['img_url']
                             );
                array_push($offer_array["offers"], $offerData);
            }
            $offer_array["error"] = false;
            echoRespnse(200, $offer_array);
        });

function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);

    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');

    echo json_encode($response);
}

$app->run();
?>
```

Any idea whats causing this error??
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run the print_r command on the **$headers** and see what are you getting in the there . I think the key is not being set or its not coming at all to your code

Okay then do this before line 28 :

```
    $api_key=null ;
```

Try this once and let me know .

This is the error :

```
           $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
           echo $apiKey;
```

But the echo is printing the  wrong variable .It should be

```
           echo $api_key;
```

Comment: I get the following output in addition to previous error:

`Array
(
    [Host] => localhost
    [Connection] => keep-alive
    [User-Agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36
    [Authorization] => b2c58c89674ffa83ba9bc6b0cc5bbeda
    [Accept] => */*
    [DNT] => 1
    [Accept-Encoding] => gzip, deflate, sdch
    [Accept-Language] => en-US,en;q=0.8
)`

Comment: Nope. It still shows the same error.
I think the error arises at `if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {` line, becoz no break statements work after that.

Comment: Found the error,What you pointed out is ture, but that was not the thing that was causing the error...
It is this `if ($isValidApiKey($api_key) === false)` 
isValidApiKey() is a function, it was a silly mistake.
Anyways thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey , glad I could help . but I was looking from the point of view of the error thrown by slim .